# git commit push merge, só eu que tenho problemas?

Tags: git

Boa tarde pessoal, sempre que estou trabalhando com git com mais de um desenvolvedor, usando aquelas funcionalidades de criar branch, 
comitar e fazer merge no master tem problemas justamente no merge?
Acontece q outras pessoas já fizeram merge antes de ti, então surge os conflitos dai começa um passo a passo do sufoco com tentativas e falhas 
que nunca solucionam o merge, depois de um sofrimento decido pegar cada uma das alterações, deixar apenas um branch, excluir os demais, e ficar 
comitando os merges um a um no master..

Enfim, ta na cara que sou um péssimo usuário do git, mas é só eu que sofro?

Será que o svn não era mais legal por que as coisas(merge) não prometiam ser automaticas que nem no git?

O SVN só dava conflito se a mesma linha fosse alterada, então eu tinha que ter o trabalho de escolher qual alteração queria, enfim.
No Git mudar uma virgula no arquivo da conflito e tenho que sofrer para fazer o merge, utilizando eclipse então nem se fala pois a pasta 
target que tem os class fica dando diferença, e o ignore não me respeita como eu gostaria.

Esse desabafo é para saber se outras pessoas tem esse tipo de problema com o git e como fizeram para melhorar a forma de trabalho com o git.

Comment: Provavelmente não, mas também provavelmente tem jeito de fazer melhor. Pelo que está dizendo parece que vocês acreditam que o Git faz mágica. Já pensou em voltar trabalhar com era no SVN? E aí quem sabe ir dando um passo de cada vez? O Git realmente é para dar bem menos conflitos que o SVN. Mas não pode fazer uma bagunça completa. Se está dando mais conflitos em coisas simples, algo muito errado está acontecendo. E não tem como ajudar só por esse relato. Eu vou chutar que estão usando o Git da maneira errada, mas não tem como afirmar ou dizer o que, não tem detalhes. Nem se ise dá para por aí.

Comment: sobre oque você falou, o colega no comentário abaixo complementa com o exemplo, estamos usando de uma forma que complica a vida mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o @Maniero disse, a ideia é que com o Git haja menos conflitos em relação ao SVN.

Talvez o problema esteja no workflow que estão a usar. Então, vou tentar partilhar aqui qual fluxo de trabalho tenho usado quando estou a trabalhar com git.

Minha primeira regra: Nunca trabalhar na *branch* `master`.

Segunda regra: Se tiver mais de um desenvolvedor, ninguém faz o push diretamente para a *branch* `master`. Tenho sempre uma segunda *branch* (`develop`) onde todos fazem *pull requests*.

Em outras palavras, o desenvolvedor/programador, trabalha numa nova branch herdada da `develop`:

> $ git checkout -b minha_nova_funcionalidade develop

Depois de concluída a funcionalidade, o desenvolvedor faz o *pull request* para a branch `develop`. O gestor do projeto revê o código e caso esteja tudo aos conforme, aceita o PR e faz o *merge*.

Quando chegar o momento de lançar a nova versão a partir do que foi feito na *branch* `develop`, o gestor cria uma nova *branch* para o efeito:

> $ git checkout -b release-1.2 develop

Nesta nova *branch* o gestor poderá fazer alguma alteração como a mudança do número de versão, a atualização do arquivo *changelog* ou `README`.

Neste ponto o gestor pode fazer o *merge* (todos os testes feitos) da nova *branch* para `master`:

> $ git checkout master
>   $ git merge --no-ff release-1.2
>   $ git tag -a v1.2
>   $ git push origin master

E fazer o mesmo *merge* para a *branch develop*

> $ git checkout develop
>   $ git merge --no-ff release-1.2
>   $ git push origin develop

... E assim sucessivamente

Com isso, evito problemas de conflito, ou que um outro dev cometa uma borrada ao editar um arquivo que não deveria ser editado.

É importante que cada membro da equipe trabalhe numa solução especifica, evitando assim que o outro dev edite o mesmo arquivo. Para casos que seja necessário editar o mesmo arquivo, desde que não seja a mesma linha, o Git é inteligente o suficiente para fazer o *merge* automático.

Comment: vou organizar os branchs aqui e tentar fazer dessa forma, parece uma boa. obrigado.